# FileNotFoundError error while trying to rename the symlinks using os.rename

Tags: python, rename

Say I have couple of symlinks (pointed to real files)

```
> ls -l
akc.tsv ->/usr/data/akc.tsv
vkc.csv ->/usr/data/vkc.tsv
```

And now I need to rename the `akc.tsv` and `vkc.csv`. I have tried using

```
os.rename (akc.tsv, newname)
```

However, it is throwing error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'akc.tsv' -> 'newname'
```

I would like to rename the symlinks, and it would be really great if someone can give their suggestions or possible directions!!

Thank you